# Sort an Array of Objects (People) by Last Name C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, object

I am trying to sort an array of objects by last name using different algorithms.

Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to make the function actually sort the array and save the sorted one, so that it can be printed later.

It prints out the same thing before and after the sorting.

I set the sample size of the printed objects to be 10, so that it is more manageable, but there are absolutely no changes in the order, although the data file is not pre-sorted.

What am I doing wrong?

### Code:

```
void swap(Person a, Person b){
    Person temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
void bubbleSort(Person a[], const int size){
     for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++){     
     for (int j = 0; j < size-i-1; j++){
           if (a[j].getLastName() > a[j+1].getLastName())
              swap(a[j], a[j+1]);
       }
    }
}
void selectionSort(Person a[], const int size){
    int minimal_position;
    for (int i=0; i < size-1; i++) {
        minimal_position = i;
        for (int j=i+1; j < size; j++) {
            if (a[j].getLastName() < a[minimal_position].getLastName())
                minimal_position=j;
        }
        if (minimal_position != i){
            swap(a[i], a[minimal_position]);
        }
    }
}
void incertionSort(Person a[], const int size){
    int i, j;
    Person temp;
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        temp.setPerson(a[i]);
        int j = i-1;
        while (j >= 0 && a[j].getLastName() > temp.getLastName()){
           a[j+1] = a[j];
           j = j-1;
        }
        a[j+1] = temp;
   }
}
void chooseSorting(Person a[], const int size){
    char algorithm;
    cout << "Choose your desired sorting method \n";
    cout << "Type b for bubble sorting, s for selection sorting, ";
    cout << "or i for insertion sorting: \n";
    cout << "Method: ";
    cin >> algorithm;
    cout << endl;
    if(algorithm != 'b' && algorithm != 'i' && algorithm != 's'){
        cout << "Please, choose i, b, or s \n";
        chooseSorting(a, size);
        cout << "Sorted \n";
    }
    else if (algorithm == 'b'){
        bubbleSort(a, size);
        cout << "Sorted \n";
    }
    else if (algorithm == 's'){
        selectionSort(a, size);
        cout << "Sorted \n";
    }
    else {
        incertionSort(a, size);
        cout << "Sorted \n";
    }
}
int main() {
    const int i = chooseDatabase();
    const int size = databaseSize(i);
    const string database_name = chooseDatabaseName(i);
    readFileIntoArray(database_name, arr, size);
    printArray(arr, 10);
    chooseSorting(arr, size);
    printArray(arr, 10);
    return 0;
}
```

I think I am doing something wrong with the way I pass the array, but i cannot quite figure out another way to do that that would not set my compiler on fire (g++).

Comment: You could use `std::swap` which actually works.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the swap function.
You are passing the object by value, you need to pass it by reference.

```
void swap(Person &a, Person &b)
```

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you test your swap() is working or not?
You should write it in this way:

```
void swap(Person &a, Person &b){
    Person temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
```

For the reason that your code is operating the copy of Person a and Person b, and have no effort on the a and b in your sort function.